# Bing search string

Tags: javascript, html, bing

I was wondering if I could construct my own Bing Uri search string's based on the following information.

I am trying to search over a certain domain and locale.  For instance;

search here "http//:www.kotaku.com" for "playstation 3" and take me to a bing results page that is in es-es locale language (spanish.)

Can anyone give a link for more reading or an easy solution?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Looks like the Bing API returns search results for one to use in their own site.  This is not what I want, I just want to redirect to the Bing page with the results I want.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Bing API 2.0](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/API%20Basics.pdf) you can search like so:

```
http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?AppId=<YOUR_APP_ID>&Query=<QUERY_STRING>&sources=web
```

`QUERY_STRING` is URL encoded string containing all your params.

This document also contains some example how to use service with JavaScript, PHP and C#.

For your example it should be like:

```
playstation%203%20site:www.kotaku.com%20language:es
```

or in human readable format:

```
playstation 3 site:www.kotaku.com language:es
```

You can [get your `APP_ID` here](http://www.bing.com/developers/createapp.aspx) absolutely free.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering myself how we can come up with Bing search strings like the one found on Avant's Forum Site:

http://forum.avantbrowser.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=14092

In Avant Browser, we can input search strings so we can automatically use that particular search engine whenever we type a word on the search box. I wanted to use Bing ever since Google made ga-ga over their safe search goo-goo. Problem was I didn't know how to syntax that. Hope this helps you in the same way that I'm asking for help myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest for you is to try to build up your advanced query using the site and then look at the format. For your query I can build up this url:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=playstation+3+language%3Aes+site%3Awww.kotaku.com

The %3A is a url encoded colon.

So basically you can apply advanced parameters as language:es or site:mysite.com (where the colon is url encoded).

Comment: I tried the URL above and it didn't return any search results.

Comment: I gave you the format, I didn't say that it would return any results ;-)

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, seems strange that a search for Playstation 3 would return no results from Kotaku.com.  I am thinking I just need to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in English add language:en in your URL. For example, if the search term is "test" then your URL will be http://www.bing.com/search?q=test+language%3Aen